# how can import file using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

this is my simple php code i can import file using this code.but i have to implement in my project codeigniter.how can i change.

```
<?php 

$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','12345');
if (!$connect) { 
    die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 

$cid =mysql_select_db('test',$connect); 
// supply your database name

define('CSV_PATH','C:/wamp/www/csvfile/'); 
// path where your CSV file is located

    $csv_file = CSV_PATH . "infotuts.csv"; // Name of your CSV file
    $csvfile = fopen($csv_file, 'r');
    $theData = fgets($csvfile);
    $i = 0;
    while (!feof($csvfile)) {
        $csv_data[] = fgets($csvfile);
        $csv_array = explode(",", $csv_data[$i]);
        $insert_csv = array();
        $insert_csv['ID'] = $csv_array[0];
        $insert_csv['name'] = $csv_array[1];
        $insert_csv['email'] = $csv_array[2];
        $query = "INSERT INTO csvdata(ID,name,email) 
VALUES('','".$insert_csv['name']."','".$insert_csv['email']."')";
        $n=mysql_query($query, $connect );
        $i++;
    }
    fclose($csvfile);

echo "File data successfully imported to database!!";
mysql_close($connect);
?>
```

this code is working fine but i have to change in codeigniter.please guide how to .................implement this code in codeigniter............how its work in ci................

Comment: Did you tried it on codeigniter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply like this:

```
/*
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','12345');
if (!$connect) { 
    die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 

$cid =mysql_select_db('test',$connect); 
// supply your database name

*/

class something extends CI_Controller{


    function import(){
        define('CSV_PATH','./csvfile/');    #make a folder "csvfile" in your project root 
        // path where your CSV file is located

            $csv_file = CSV_PATH . "infotuts.csv"; // Name of your CSV file
            $csvfile = fopen($csv_file, 'r');
            $theData = fgets($csvfile);
            $i = 0;
            while (!feof($csvfile)) {
                $csv_data[] = fgets($csvfile);
                $csv_array = explode(",", $csv_data[$i]);
                $insert_csv = array();
                $insert_csv['ID'] = $csv_array[0];
                $insert_csv['name'] = $csv_array[1];
                $insert_csv['email'] = $csv_array[2];
                //$query = "INSERT INTO csvdata(ID,name,email) VALUES('','".$insert_csv['name']."','".$insert_csv['email']."')";
                //$n=mysql_query($query, $connect );
                //$i++;
                $this->model->save_data( $insert_csv );
            }
            fclose($csvfile);

        echo "File data successfully imported to database!!";
    }
}


/*
mysql_close($connect);
*/


#model function
function save_data( $save_data ){
    $this->db->insert('table_name', $save_data ); #edited here
    echo $this->db->last_query();
    return 1;
}
```

Then call the `import function` like this:

```
http://domain.com/something/import
```

Comment: Okay, have you changed the controller name or not? just copy the function from the above code. And be specific what error are you getting at which line etc.

Comment: i change first time imported .next time i am getting File data successfully imported to database!but its not importing actualy

Comment: Debug your code with `$this->db->last_query();` paste this line in the model function. It shows the last query executed in the database. See above I have updated the model function. There was a spelling mistake as well in `insert`.

Comment: thanks its working.any idea about first we upload then it will import how its possible in codeigniter

Comment: Sure just read about how to upload files in codeigniter, then just replace the above function to read that file instead of hardcoded filename. Read the `CI` documentation on `upload` : http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: hey i can upload but where should i call this import function after upload  the file.@Nil'z

Comment: Keep your `upload function` in the same controller as your `import function`. Now just after uploading, call the import function like this from within the upload function : `$this->import($file_name)` and make the necessary changes in the `import function` to make it accept dynamic file name. Clear enough?

Comment: function readExcel()
 { 
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $this->load->library('upload');
       if (!empty($_FILES['file']))
          {
              $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/';
     $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
     $config['max_size'] = '1000';
     $config['max_width']  = '10000';
     $config['max_height']  = '10000';
     $this->upload->initialize($config);
      $this->upload->do_upload('file');
      $file_data = $this->upload->data();
         $this->import('rr.csv');

          }
  } this is my upload function what should i change.